# angular2-highcharts import module highcharts-more

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic2, angular2-highcharts

I'm using the angular2-highcharts(v0.4.1) component in my Ionic2(v2.0.0) project.

When I run my page, I have an [error 7 from highcharts.](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17)

I tried add this code on my angular component, without success...

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.js';
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

And this...

```
declare var require: any;
const Highcharts = require('../../../node_modules/highcharts/highstock.src');
const HighchartsMore = require('../../../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more.js');
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

Anyone had add some component to this module? or know some library to use highcharts on angular2?

---

Ionic information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v4.1.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Try to use angular-higcharts, it was updated recently nd you can load any modules from highcharts

Answer (score 2):

I got it working like this (im using vanilla highcharts from npm, not angular2-highcharts, tho!):

```
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

and in the constructor:

```
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

Hope this helps!